# Problem understanding notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions

I'm learning about generating functions and in the opening explanations my book (and various sources) claim:

[image]

$$a_n = 1 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0, \ \ \ f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$$.

I read this as:

The sum of the $nth$ term of a series where every term is $1$ is equal to $$\frac{1}{1-n}$$.

But this doesn't make sense. Look at the 5th term: $$1+1+1+1+1 = 5$$ but this is not consistent with the formula: $$\frac{1}{1-5} = \frac{1}{-4}$$

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What is $f$? This question isn't clear.

Comment: Let me edit the question with the entire explanation of the book. Please don't down vote in the meanwhile.

Comment: The fact that $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + \dots = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$ is a *formal* identity. If you want to plug in actual numbers into it, it's only valid for $|x| < 1$. Try for instance $x = \frac12$. Then $1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \dots = \frac{1}{1-\frac12} = 2$. (It's the infinite sum on the left-hand side.) And a way to prove the formal identity is to call the sum $S$, and observe that $(1-x)S = (1-x)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots) = 1-x \,+\, x-x^2 \,+\, x^2-x^3 \,+\, x^3-x^4 \,+\, \dots = 1$, so as $(1-x)S = 1$, we say $S = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of an (ordinary) generating function is that if $f(x)$ generates the sequence $a_n$, then: $$a_n = f^{(n)}(0)/n!\ .$$

Here we have $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1\cdot x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$ where $a_n=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: When you say $$a_n = f^{(n)}(0)/n!\ .$$ do you mean the sum of all terms up until $n$ of a sequence $a_n$ equals $$ f^{(n)}(0)/n!\ .$$ ?

Comment: No, a generating function will give you the elements $a_n$, not the sum of them.  So $f^{(n)}(0)/n!$ is simply the $n$th term of the sequence.

Comment: When you say elements, do you mean THE element $a_n$ or a list of elements leading up to it??

Comment: I mean *the* element $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

All they are saying is the well-known Taylor expansion of the geometric series:

$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + \cdots
$$

Note that the coefficient of each power of $x$ is 1. That is, if we write

$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
$$

then $a_n = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: To me it is not at all obvious that $$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + \cdots$$

This is the part that I don't understand.

Comment: Ah, that's fair. There are a number of ways to see this: the simplest is probably to look at
$$
\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n
$$
so if $|x| < 1$, you can take the limit as $n \to \infty$ of both sides...

Comment: If you aren't perfectly clear about the above equality, try multiplying both sides by $1-x$.